# Passing multiple variable via session id and fetching variable data on another domain

Tags: php, session, cross-site

So far I have used session id as to pass a string via url and fetch that string on another domain.

Is there a way with which I can generate a session id for multiple variables and pass it via url, so those information can be extracted on another page from the fetched session id.

If its possible how to generate such a session id and then how to extract information on another page?

This is how I send string

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
session_start();
$session_id = 'user';
header("location: http://anotherdomain.com/receive.php?session_id=".$session_id );
```

And the code to receive my string is

```
session_id($_GET['session_id']);
session_start();
$_SESSION["var_name"] = session_id();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

The above codes work perfectly. I need to change it in a manner that I can pass 2 or more variables.

Comment: Are you trying to pass a collection of parameters via the URL so you can use the $_GET variable to retrieve the variables in a different file? If so, you can serialise your parameters into a single string and pass that through. However, I'd suggest you not pass parameters via the URL, perhaps use POST or session cookies?

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you paste the code for "passing the string via url" and the one to "fetch that string on the other domain" to your question? People may help you better based on what you have done so far...

Comment: While it is rather a lot of coding, a sure way to do this, is to create your own session_set_save_handler, use it to create a sess_xyz123 file.  Then, knowing the portion of the sess_xyz123 filename, use that to have whatever scripts you need, read that session file, and grab the params.

Comment: @Theston.EFox : yes, exactly what I am trying to do, can you show me how to do this by modifying my above codes?

Comment: @Armfoot : I have updated tthe question with code to pass single string. Please have a look!